# omniture clickmap implementation on buttons, non-true link

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

Is it possible to implement omniture tracking on buttons or non  links or  that does nothing, maybe opening up a lightbox, google pin etc..?

I tried to put onclick=s_objectID=xxxx on these and it is however not tracking. Only tags with true links works.

Has anyone has a good suggestion or workaround?

Cheers

```
`a href="#" onclick="s_objectID=trackThisLink"`
`button onclick="s_objectID=trackThisLink"`
```

Comment: Can you add the source code for the link that doesn't show up as a link in omniture?

Answer (score 0):

You will want to manually send a custom link image request in to have this data sent. There is a link tracking white paper within the SiteCatalyst interface you can use to get additional details on how to implement this.